# Play Framework takes too long to load with hibernate

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, playframework-2.2

My project uses Play Framework 2 with Hibernate and Postgres, but every time I have to reload to test something it takes a lot of time (about 2 minutes) to finally serve my request the first time (development mode).

So basically, its taking a lot of time to go from

```
[info] play - database [default] connected at jdbc:postgresql://myDBConnection
```

to

```
[info] play - Application started (Dev)
```

I tried lowering the log levels but nothing logs between those two so I have no idea what's going on in there that takes so much time, but it's seriously affecting my ability to work since it takes so long to load.

Is there any obvious or easy fix for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case anyone else sees this, I managed to fix it by removing the JPA mappings and just using plain old hibernate like I would use it everywhere else. My connections went to 30+ secs in startup to about 2 secs. Much better!

Answer (score 0):

This is normal for `Play! Framework` running in `DEV` mode.

In Dev Mode the server is launched with the `auto-reload` and `hot swap` enabled by default, meaning that for each **request** Play will validate the project and recompile required sources. Also if there are multiple changes (mostly changes in your model) the application will restart automatically.

Also I am guessing that on your applications start - you have some test data that is loaded into your database. (If yes, this reload will happen each time your model changes and your application is restarted [automatically]. In addition the JPA validator will make sure your relation model matches your JPA definitions.)

Note that this only happens on the initial request. If this is happening on each request, then you have some fault SQL that is taking very long to execute.

Comment: Yes this only happens on the initial request, and I know it reloads each time on dev mode but 2 minutes?!